# Cannot implicitly convert type Generic.List to Model type

Tags: c#

Check the code below. The problem is from `lk_GetThirdpartyDataByAsins` stored procedure i am getting the `ThirdPartyData` Model type data but error says its unable to convert them to `ThirdPartyData`. Any way to solve it? Thanks in advance

Error picture:

[image]

```
using (var ctx = new db_exampleEntities())
{
    string patternedString = string.Join("", itemstoUpdate.Select(tpdToString));
    ThirdPartyData MissedData = ctx.lk_GetThirdpartyDataByAsins(patternedString, itemstoUpdate.FirstOrDefault().Type).ToList();
    itemstoUpdate.AddRange(MissedData);
}
```

Comment: Could you show us `ThirdPartyData ` class?

Comment: You're trying to convert a `List<T>` to `T`.  That won't work.  It returns more than one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to convert a `List<ThirdPartyData>` to `ThirdPartyData`

Change this line :

```
ThirdPartyData MissedData = ctx.lk_GetThirdpartyDataByAsins(patternedString, itemstoUpdate.FirstOrDefault().Type).ToList();
```

to :

```
         List<ThirdPartyData> MissedData = ctx.lk_GetThirdpartyDataByAsins(patternedString, itemstoUpdate.FirstOrDefault().Type)
         .Select(s=> new ThirdPartyData(){
               a= s.a,
               ...
               z=s.z
            }).ToList()
```

Comment: NO this not works at all. Same error

Comment: I may need to map type in model. c# create custom complex type. Can u tell me how to map?

Comment: @johnCogdle Then you need to expand your question, because it isn't at all clear what the actual issue is or what you are trying to do.

Comment: @johnCogdle See my updated answer.

Comment: Exact answer. Thanks brother